# The king fell off the board

Tags: problems, records

Give a position (White to move) with the bK missing. If it is inserted on any legal square, it is mated in one move by the wQ, with a different mate for each square.

(Point of side conditions: If you only stipulate "can be legally inserted on n squares where it is mated, and also m others where it isn't" my record is n=13. Records for PNBRK with m=0 are known and neigh beatable. This record for this question is completely unknown.)

Clarifying example for wK instead of wQ:

```
[FEN "4R3/8/p1P3P1/4K2R/3Q4/pN3PB1/2p12p1/1B3r2 w - - 0 0"]
```

The squares c7, g7, b5, e2 are the only legal squares where the bK may stand. On each it is mated, by Kd5, Kf5, Kd6, Kf4 respectively.